# re.sub not replacing if the whole string doesn't match

Tags: python, regex, string, text

Bit of a regex newbie here.
I have this string:

`year_with_txt = 'foo 1999'` and

`year_only = '1999'`.

I want to omit any 4 consecutive digits.
When I do it this way:

`re.sub(r'^[0-9]{4}$', '', year_only)`

or

`re.sub(r'^\d{4}$', '', year_only)`

it works. However, with other text in, it doesn't:

`re.sub(r'^[0-9]{4}$', '', year_with_txt)`

or

`re.sub(r'^\d{4}$', '', year_with_txt)`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why on earth is this tagged `r`?

Comment: Honestly, I wasn't planning to. But stackoverflow tagged it as recommended. Sorry :)

Comment: Short answer: it's matching only the year because you told it to only match the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is your `^` and `$` tokens. Those refer to the start and end of the string respectively.

`re.sub(r'\d{4}', '', year_with_txt)` works.

Output:

`'foo '`

Note: you defined the string as `year_with_txt`, but referred to it in the rest of the code as `year_with_text`.